# Override back button press in uwp

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

As is mentioned in [oficial doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt465734.aspx), there is possibility to handle back button press, but I can't handle it to do only my logic not to go back anyway. So my code looks like:

```
//declare event
public event EventHandler<BackRequestedEventArgs> BackRequested;

public MainPage() {
  InitializeComponent();

  // tie my event with back action
  SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += OnBackRequested;
}

// handle the back event
private void OnBackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e) {
  //need to do only my logic here  - do NOT go back 
}
```

So is there a way to get this behavior. I'd like it as Android do it:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  //does only my logic
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set argument parameter `e.Handled` to true so that it lets implement your own logic and you can choose whether to go back through the stack.

```
    private void OnBackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

        if (rootFrame.CanGoBack)
        {
            e.Handled = true;

            if(condition) //my condition is true so go back through the stack
                rootFrame.GoBack();
            }
        }
    }
```